# Is it good /Fine to connect website on iis as administrator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-hosting, administration

Is it good /Fine to connect website on iis as administrator user and not as regular user given by host company? 
I need this to download pdf(rotative) for example..
 and i notice that  it is obligatory(for default application pool in basic setting to connect as administrator) even to enable the website lunch and work..

so i need to know if connecting as administrator - (in advance setting->identity) or in basic setting - is a problem or not fine for **websites** and is it true that if:

The web application runs as admin, then anyone who wants to run a known exploit (either in IIS, ASP.NET, Rotativa or your application code), will be able to do so and have access to the entire machine

Comment: `The web application runs as admin, then anyone who wants to run a known exploit (either in IIS, ASP.NET, Rotativa or your application code), will be able to do so and have access to the entire machine`. Yes, that is true, and is the major security concern. You would typically run your website as an account that has the *least privileges* required to accomplish it's task. This reduces the attack scope if an exploit is found. This is known as the "Principle of least privilege"

Comment: Thanks in advanced info and advanced Title: "Principle of least privilege"" ..This is an interesting topic i will search for it.. thanks

Comment: Yes your application should run under different account. You can create separate user for this purpose.